# How to view circuit details (including security keys) in Tor?

Tags: circuit, encryption, session, key

I wonder if its possible to find the session keys for Tor's circuit for a hidden service such as facebookcorewwwi.onion (or public site)?

[image]

There are 4 keys used in connecting to a site:

1. Key between tor client and entry guard
2. Key between tor client and middle relay
3. Key between tor client and exit node
4. ssl session key (if the service is using ssl/tls)

I have checked [nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/) project, but could not find any information about encryption details of a circuit. The output from nyx is something similar to this (image from [this link](https://www.slideshare.net/jmoc25/osint-python-extracting-information-from-tor-network-and-darkweb)):
[image: https://www.slideshare.net/jmoc25/osint-python-extracting-information-from-tor-network-and-darkweb]

Please help me in this matter.

Comment: The tor code does not expose the session stream keys for each circuit hop (there are keys for both the forward and backward direction at each hop). You would need to modify the tor source code to log these, or expose them via the control protocol.

Comment: Thanks for answer. By means of control protocol, you say that accessing tor through 9051 by telnet? If so, do you know the command? I didn't find anything in tor spec.

Comment: Tor's control protocol is documented in the [control-spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) document, but if you want to interact with it I recommend using the Python [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) library rather than telnet.

Comment: The example you were looking for:
https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/list_circuits.html